# Is there any library getNLMultibutton involved in?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there any standard library in SuiteScript?

For example I want to use functions like `getNLMultibuttonByName()` or `onMainButtonClick()` that Netsuite supports, but I met `undefined error` when I use this in my own script.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are undocumented and used internally by Netsuite and are not supported for use in user scripts. For a reference of the Netsuite API, see the [SuiteScript documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=book_N2902317.html) (login required).

Answer (score 0):

> **Remember :** 
>   `getNLMultibuttonByName()` or `onMainButtonClick()` are Netsuite specific UI  functions and are not a part of regular Suitescript.

If you want to simulate the same behavior using a button then probably you can do something like this

```
function onLoad(type, form, request){
     if(type=='view') {
            form.addButton('custpage_button','Custom Button',"getNLMultiButtonByName('multibutton_convertinvt').onMainButtonClick(this);return false;");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

getNLMultiButtonByName is an undocumented NetSuite client side function call used by NetSuite.  I've successfully used the line of code below in client side scripts to mimic the action of pressing the "Submit" button for example on a Project record.  You don't need to attach/reference a library in your script to use the following:

```
getNLMultiButtonByName('multibutton_submitter').onMainButtonClick(this);
```